# Mapping a different SQL server to a SP farm

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sql

I want to map a new SQL server and content DBs to my SP farm.

What are the steps to achieve this and what are the things i have to take care off?

Comment: what you want, simply add another sql server into the farm or move all the database to the new Sql Server?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use SQL Aliases. Basically you backup and move all your databases to the different sql server, stop all sharepoint services, and through aliases you can point the backend to a different sql server:

[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725(v=office.15).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mike.But SQL server instance is only added to sharepoint. Is it possible that i can create the SQL aliases in Central admin now?

Comment: Your options may be limited to either having a sql alias (for those servers) point to a new sql server, or, backing up for the farm and using the powershell cmdlet `Rename-SPServer` : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607556.aspx